# What is $(-1)^\sqrt{2}$?

Tags: complex-numbers, real-numbers, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, integers

How do you reason that $(-1)^\sqrt{2}$ is a complex number based on the following statements:

1. *$(-1)^{p/q}$ is a complex number if $p$ is odd and $q$ is even integers.*
2. *Rational numbers are dense in the real line.*
3. *Exponential is a continuous function*.

Another question arises as what $(-1)^\sqrt{2}$ represents on the real line?

Comment: $\sqrt{2}$ isn't rational, so you can't write it as $p/q$, so I'm unsure if your method will work.

Comment: That being said, we have that $(-1) = i^2$, so $(-1)^{\sqrt 2} = (i^2)^{\sqrt{2}} = i^{2\sqrt 2} = i^{\sqrt{8}}$.  As $i^k$ is only real if $k = 2m$ for some $m$, we should expect $i^{\sqrt 8}$ to be complex.

Comment: @Mark The rule $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$ does not apply for complex bases (i.e., $a=i$ here).  See my posted solution for the correct way forward.  -Mark also

Comment: None of the answers here does not answer your question in the way you want it to be answered.

Comment: That is true. It might be because the assumption on the continuity is not useful as we talk about branches.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Note that in general $z^c$ is defined as $e^{c\log(z)}$, where $\log(z)$ is the **multi-valued** complex logarithm given by $\log(z)=\log(|z|)+i\arg(z)$.

Here, we have

$$\begin{align}
(-1)^\sqrt2&=e^{\sqrt2\log(-1)}\\\\
&=e^{\sqrt2 (i(2n+1)\pi)}\\\\
&=e^{i(2n+1)\pi \sqrt2} \\\\
&=\cos((2n+1)\pi \sqrt2)+i\sin((2n+1)\pi\sqrt2)
\end{align}$$

where $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

If we choose the principal branch of the logarithm (i.e., $n=0$), then $-1=e^{i\pi}$ and we have

$$(-1)^\sqrt2=\cos(\pi\sqrt2)+i\sin(\pi\sqrt2)$$

---

Now, if $p$ is an odd integer and $q$ is an even integer, then we have

$$\begin{align}
(-1)^{p/q}&=e^{(p/q)\log(-1)}\\\\
&=e^{(p/q) (i(2n+1)\pi)}\\\\
&=e^{i(2n+1)p\pi  /q} \\\\
&=\cos((2n+1)p\pi/q )+i\sin((2n+1)p \pi/q )
\end{align}$$

If $p$ is odd, then certainly $p(2n+1)$ is also odd and $p(2n+1)/q$ is not an integer.  Therefore, $\sin((2n+1)p\pi/q)\ne 0$ and $(-1)^{p/q}$ has a non-zero imaginary part.

---

By continuity of the complex exponential function, for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a $\delta>0$ such that

$$\left|e^{i(2n+1)p\pi/q}-e^{i(2n+1)\sqrt 2\,\pi}\right|<\epsilon$$

whenever $|(2n+1)p\pi /q-(2n+1)\sqrt2 \pi|<\delta$.

By the density of the rational numbers, for this $\delta>0$ there exist integers $(2n+1)p$ and $q$ such that $|(2n+1)p\pi /q-(2n+1)\sqrt2 \pi|<\delta$.

And we are done!

Comment: Alright, but how can that be related to the statements I mentioned in the questions?

Comment: I've edited to include a section that addresses the question regarding $(-1)^{p/q}$ where $p$ is odd and $q$ is even.

Comment: Precisely, now you can see why I asked that question; because this reasoning tells us $\sqrt{2}$ behaves like an odd number divided by an even number.

Answer (score 2):

As Mark pointed out in the comment,

$$(-1)^{\sqrt{2}}=(i^2)^{\sqrt{2}}=i^{2\sqrt{2}}\text{.}$$

Now we know that

$$i^{2\sqrt{2}}=(e^{\pi i/2})^{2\sqrt{2}}=e^{\pi i\sqrt{2}}\text{,}$$

and by De Moivre's formula,

$$e^{\pi i\sqrt{2}}=\cos(\pi\sqrt{2})+i\sin(\pi\sqrt{2})$$

which is complex (and transcendental).

Not sure how to use your given fact, though, since $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

Comment: It is irrational, but note that the rational numbers are dense in the real line. Also, exponentiation is a continuous function.

Comment: @Sara Winslet Good idea. Perhaps take approximate rational numbers $\frac{p_1}{q_1}$ and $\frac{p_2}{q_2}$ that are sufficiently close enough such that $\frac{p_1}{q_1}<\sqrt{2}<\frac{p_2}{q_2}$?

Comment: There are also other issues; for example, $(-1)^{2/4}$ is real, but the same number $(-1)^{1/2}$ is imaginary. There has to be some subtleties that I am ignoring.

Comment: This answer disregards the multi-valued nature of the complex logarithm and is therefore incomplete.

Comment: @SaraWinslet when using the principal branch of exponentiation, as is common, we have $(-1)^{2/4}=(-1)^{1/2}=i$ which is imaginary, so $(-1)^{2/4}$ is most definitely not real.

Comment: @Calconym Why not $i^6$ ?